React Native: Execution failed for task ':vision-camera-face-detector:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
I'm trying to develop a react native feature to detect the faces. Currently, I'm using the following recommended libraries to achieve this:
"dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.6",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-vision-camera-face-detector": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^1.5.0",
    "vision-camera-face-detector": "^0.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }

And this is what the basic code setup looks like:
import {runOnJS} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {
  useCameraDevice,
  useFrameProcessor,
  Camera,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';

import {scanFaces, Face} from 'vision-camera-face-detector';

export default function App() {
  const [openCamera, setOpenCamera] = useState(false);
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);

  const [faces, setFaces] = useState<Face[]>(null);

  const device = useCameraDevice('front');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({faces});
  }, [faces]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const status = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      setHasPermission(status === 'authorized');
    })();
  }, []);

  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor(frame => {
    'worklet';
    const scannedFaces = scanFaces(frame);
    console.log({scannedFaces});
    runOnJS(setFaces)(scannedFaces);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      }}>
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 32, textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'bold'}}>
          Welcome to Arena
        </Text>
      </View>
      {device != null && hasPermission ? (
        <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
          <Camera
            device={device}
            isActive={true}
            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
            frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            borderRadius: 20,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            maxWidth: 300,
            padding: 16
          }}
          onPress={() => setOpenCamera(true)}>
          <Text>Open Camera</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

I'm getting an error after installation of 'react-native-vision-camera':

I updated my babel.config.js as follows:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['react-native-worklets-core/plugin'],
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanFaces'],
      },
    ],
  ],
};

And also re-build the gradle inside the android folder as follows: ./gradlew clean
But even after that, the code is not compiling. I tried looking into similar questions on SO and the official documentation Issues section, but nothing has helped so far.
If anyone can help look into it, it'd be appreciated.
